# How to use TClientDataSet to locate containing string

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, datasnap, tclientdataset, midas-server

I'm using Delphi 2007.

I know I can use the `.locate` method of a `TClientDataSet` to locate a record, like this:

```
myClient.locate('name','John',[loPartialKey,loCaseInsensitive]);
```

But let's say I want to locate any record with 'John' containing on its name, something as:

> name like '%John%'

Would do it in a regular SQL expression.

Is this possible using the `.locate` method?

It seems the `[loPartialKey]` works as starting with instead of containing.

Comment: Have you try to use the lookup method not sure if is in 2007? https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29176

Answer (score 3):

In .Locate, loPartialKey matches from the first character in the field value, so you can't do what you want using only .Locate.

However, the Filter property of TClientDataSet *can* contain `like`, as in
setting the CDS's Filter property to

```
AField like '%w%'  // matches all AField values containing `w`
```

or, in code,

```
  ClientDataset1.Filtered := False;
  ClientDataset1.Filter :=  'AField like ' + QuotedStr('%' + edFilter.Text + '%');
  ClientDataset1.Filtered := True;
```

so you may be able to use the filter to narrow down the number of rows and use Locate to find a specfic one, or simply iterate over the filtered rows to find the exact one you want.

Comment: Are you sure about `AField`?

Comment: @Sami:  Yes, AField being the field's name.  It certainly works in D7.

Comment: Yup, I know what did you mean but it should be a string `'FieldName'` and you should also use `QuotedStr()` for `'%w%'`. Something like `:= 'AField like ' + QuotedStr('%w%');`

Comment: @Sami, sorry, what I quoted, w/o quotes around AField works fine if entered using the propertt editor.  Thanks foir catching that.  I can't immediately see that QuotedStr would mae any difference on the RHS, but it's been a long day.

Comment: I suppose you're tired :). but a `Filter` property is a string, so when you pass the string as you're suggesting, then it'll be `'AField LIKE %w%'`. Is that valid?

Comment: Nice, did not know the filter expression can contain like !

Comment: @Sami:  I've updated it to show setting the filter in code.  Also I can confirm that when set via the `Filter` property of the CDS, the quotes around %w% aren't required, which is a bit curious as you noted.  I'll remind myself how the filter expression gets parsed and see if that reveals why.

Answer (score 0):

No. On the first part can be partially matched. As mention in the help for "Using Locate".

> Locate moves the cursor to the first row matching a specified set of
>   search criteria. In its simplest form, you pass Locate the name of a
>   column to search, a field value to match, and an options flag
>   specifying whether the search is case-insensitive or if it can use
>   partial-key matching. (Partial-key matching is when the criterion
>   string need only be a prefix of the field value.) For example, the
>   following code moves the cursor to the first row in the CustTable
>   where the value in the Company column is "Professional Divers, Ltd.":
>
> ```
> var
>   LocateSuccess: Boolean;
>   SearchOptions: TLocateOptions;
> begin
>   SearchOptions := [loPartialKey];
>   LocateSuccess := CustTable.Locate('Company', 'Professional Divers, Ltd.', SearchOptions);
> end;
> ```

ref: [Delphi online documentation: Using Locate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_Locate)

Answer (score 0):

LocateRecord internally uses DSCursor.LocateWithFilter so I believe it's possible to write custom method doing what you want

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use .FindFirst and .FindNext :

```
myDataset.Filter := 'CustomerName LIKE ' + ('*' + edtSearch.Text + '*').QuotedString;
myDataset.Filtered := False;
Found :=  myDataset.FindFirst

if Found then
```

Use .Locate when you want to search for a key that you know the exact value.

And using just Filtered := true will work, for situations that you do not mind if other records will disapear on the dbGrid.